# upgrade android Squidb and now doesn't create db

Tags: yahoo-squidb

I have upgraded Squidb to 2.0. Now when I try to create the object, it doesn't create the database.

Do I need to call any method? My understanding was that on Object create, it creates a db.

Please suggest.

Thanks,